# How to use cypress to get network call after page load

Tags: javascript, cypress

I'm trying to test an ad network call by using cypress, how can I filter the network call and get the response.
[image]

specifically for query string parameters

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this already - https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/12/23/asserting-network-calls-from-cypress-tests/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this for example:

```
it('Some test', () => {
    cy.intercept('/').as('myRequest');
    cy.visit('www.example.com');
    cy.wait('@myRequest').then((interception) => {
        cy.log(interception.response.body);
    });
});
```

To listen for only ads requests use `cy.intercept('/ads')`. Remember to put intercept before you open the page.

Reference: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept

Comment: I can get response now, but how can I get query string parameters. Also I only get one response, but there should be multiple responses.

Comment: Interception in this example contains id, response and request properties, you can call `console.log(interception)` as well as `console.log(interception.response)` and take a look in DevTools what information those objects contain. You'll see that response has `url` property, so to get it you just need `interception.response.url`. You'll need additional few lines of code  to parse out the query string parameters, but that's easily googleable.
Regarding multiple response, sorry, don't know unless you specify as many waits as there are requests (you need only one intercept)

Comment: that works, thank you so much